# Problem with PSCustomObject data collection

Tags: azure, powershell, scripting, virtual-machine, storage

I'm preparing a table with information about VM name and provision date of OS disk. I can easily retrieve that information from $VM.disks.statuses.time[0] command, if individual VM is assigned to $VM, but I when i try to collect data into table, I got an error:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:4 char:1
+ [PSCustomObject]@{
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

This is my code:

```
$VMs = Get-AzVM -status

$vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object {
[PSCustomObject]@{
"VM Name" = $_.Name
"Provision Date" = $_.disks.statuses.time[0].ToString()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, the issue was caused by the outputs of `Get-AzVM -status` and `Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <Name> -Status` are different.

The output of `Get-AzVM -status` will not has the `disks` property, but when you get individual VM status via `Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <Name> -Status`, it will have the property, so you got the error.

**`Get-AzVM -status`**:

[image]

**`Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <Name> -Status`**:

[image]

**Solution:**

To fix the issue, just to use `Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <Name> -Status` in your script.

```
$VMs = Get-AzVM -status

$vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object {

$VMstatus = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -Name $_.Name -Status

[PSCustomObject]@{
"VM Name" = $VMstatus.Name
"Provision Date" = $VMstatus.disks.statuses.time[0].ToString()
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Get-AzDisk` command to retrieve disk creation information.

```
$disks = Get-AzDisk | Where-Object { $_.Managedby }
$vmOutput = foreach ($disk in $disks) {
    [pscustomobject]@{"VM Name" = ($disk.ManagedBy -split "/")[-1]
        "Provisioned Date" = $disk.TimeCreated
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But this solution only works when all disks are managed (as these will be the only ones listed in the output).

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
```

So my guess is that something here `$_.disks.statuses.time[0].ToString()` is `$null`. Therefore you should add some `$null`checks:

```
$VMs = Get-AzVM -status

$vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.disks -and $_.disks.statuses -and $_.disks.statuses.time -and ($_.disks.statuses.time.Count -gt 0)){
       [PSCustomObject]@{
          "VM Name" = $_.Name
           "Provision Date" = $_.disks.statuses.time[0].ToString()
       }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's impossible, each VM that includes OS disk, includes that date. When I run your script, $vmOutput was null, so there must be something else going on.